# Can't take screenshot in command line with Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, screenshot, selenium-chromedriver

My final goal is to be able to take automated screenshots. For this I've been reading this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) which says that it should be as simple as this in the command line:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

But I don't get any screenshot.png files anywhere in the *current directory*, in my case C:\temp. I've also tried omitting the 'headless' parameter but the only thing that happens is that Chrome opens the website but no file is created.

The plan is to use chrome and selenium together as such:

```
public void ScreenshotPage(string url)
{
    ChromeOptions o = new ChromeOptions();

    o.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1200");
    o.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
    o.AddArgument("disable-extensions");
    o.AddArgument("headless");
    o.AddArgument(url);

    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(o))
    {
        //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); // if o.AddArgument(url) doesn't work then try this instead.
        //Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Screenshot screenshot = driver.GetScreenshot();
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(@"C:\temp\test.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

The result is a blank png-file which seems to have the right resolution.

One reason that I'm looking into headless Chrome is that my program is going to be run in a virtual machine and without a user logged in. This creates a problem for ChromeDriver's GetScreenshot() since it will use a very low resolution for taking the screenshot. I was hoping that a headless Chrome would solve this issue.

There doesn't seem to be any relevant information on the Internet, save [Using headless Chrome as an automated screenshot tool (alternative to PhantomJS)](https://github.com/schnerd/chrome-headless-screenshots) where the author has explicitly stated that he is targeting Chrome v60. I'm a bit hesitant using puppeteer since I'm writing in .NET and not so sure if current ports are

Environment: Google Chrome 63.0.3239.132 64-bit, Windows 10 (and Server 2012), Chromedriver 2.34

Comment: I tried using the commandline (well replaced the url) above and got no screenshot either - suggesting the info was out of date

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(o))
{
    Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
    ss.SaveAsFile(@"C:\temp\test.png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the code above only works in non-headless mode, ie. without the --headless argument.